# How do I mock the python decorator argument?

Tags: caching, mocking, wrapper, python-unittest, python-decorators

How do I mock a cached value in Python unit test using cachetools ? I wrote a decorator named cache_controller. I had valid reasons not to use Cachetools' decorator.
When I try to mock TTLCache objects while writing the test code, I cannot mock it. What would be the reason ?

*src/helpers/cache.py*

```
from cachetools import TTLCache

total_cache = TTLCache(maxsize=1024, ttl=600)
```

*src/wrappers/cache_controller.py*

```
from functools import wraps

def cache_controller(cache, cache_args: tuple):
    """
    :return: wrapper
    """

    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("Cache in CACHE CONROLLER:", cache)
            cache_key = tuple([kwargs[arg] for arg in cache_args])
            print("Cache key in CACHE CONROLLER:", cache_key)
            cached_value = cache.get(cache_key)
            print("Cache value in CACHE CONROLLER:", cached_value)
            
            if cached_value:
                print(f"{self.__class__.__name__} : {cache_key} : from Local Cache : {cached_value}")
                return cached_value
            
            result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)

            cache.update({cache_key: result})
            print(f"{self.__class__.__name__} : {cache_key} : Updated to Local Cache : {result}")

            return result

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

*src.run.py*

```
from .wrappers.cache_controller import cache_controller
from .helpers.cache import total_cache


class ExampleClass(object):

    @cache_controller(
        cache=total_cache,
        cache_args=("a", "b")
    )
    def example_method(self, a: int, b: int):
        return a+b
```

*test/test_cache_controller.py

```
import unittest
from cachetools.ttl import TTLCache
from src.run import ExampleClass
from unittest import TestCase, mock


class TestCacheController(TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def setUp(self):
        self.fake_cache = TTLCache(maxsize=10, ttl=3600)
        self.fake_cache.__setitem__((5, 6), 1)
        self._class = ExampleClass()

    def tearDown(self):
        self._class = None

    @ mock.patch("src.run.total_cache")
    def test_if_cache_filled(self, mock_total_cache):
        mock_total_cache.return_value = self.fake_cache

        result = self._class.example_method(a=5, b=6)
        func_expected = 11
        cache_expected = 1
        print("Result:", result)

        self.assertEqual(result, cache_expected)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

.. and run test code

```
cachetools-mock ❯ python -m test.test_cache_controller                                                                                                                                     

Cache in CACHE CONROLLER: TTLCache([], maxsize=1024, currsize=0)
Cache key in CACHE CONROLLER: (5, 6)
Cache value in CACHE CONROLLER: None

ExampleClass : (5, 6) : Updated to Local Cache : 11
Result: 11
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_if_cache_filled (__main__.TestCacheController)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sumeyyeozkaynak/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 1255, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/Users/sumeyyeozkaynak/Desktop/.optiwisdom/workspace/cachetools-mock/test/test_cache_controller.py", line 28, in test_if_cache_filled
    self.assertEqual(result, cache_expected)
AssertionError: 11 != 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen many replies that the arguments the decorators are getting are not mockable. It is correct because when the object is being tested after being mocked, the class is called again and the mocked object is overwrite.

If the import ExampleClass is imported in the Unit Test method under test, the problem will be eliminated.

```
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase, mock

class TestCacheController(TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @mock.patch.dict("src.helpers.cache.total_cache", {(5, 6): 1})
    def test_if_cache_filled(self):
        from src.run import ExampleClass
        result = ExampleClass().example_method(a=5, b=6)
        print("Result:", result)

        self.assertEqual(result, 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: or ```@mock.patch.dict("src.run.total_cache", {(5, 6): 1})``` path can be like this. both are working.